# send email on html form post without from address

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to build an anonymous feedback form where people can send me feedback. I've looked at both nodemailer and [node-sendmail](https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail), but they both don't seem to work without a from address. I know it's possible to do with php's mail, but can this be done on node.js as well?

This is the form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/send_email" method="POST">
    <textarea type="text" name="suggestions"></textarea>
</form>
```

This is a snippet of my backend. The messages get queued but they are never sent, and when I do `mailq` I see `(Deferred: connection refused by [127.0.0.1])`

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.json());

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({sendmail: true, newline:"unix", debug: true});
app.post("/send_email", function(req,res){
    transport.sendMail({
        to: "my@email.com",
        subject: "Hello World!",
        text: `You've got mail! ${req.body.suggestions}`},
        function(err, info){
            console.log("There was an error!");
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822). The `from` header is mandatory.

PHP may insert a default one, but it seems the library you are using isn't.

Add a from address. It doesn't need to belong to the person who filled in the form.

Comment: I see, do you know of any library where it isn't necessary?

Comment: No. What's wrong with just putting a from address in there?

Comment: @nodel It's not up to the library. Kind of like asking if there are any cars where you don't have to stop at stop signs.

Comment: If I use my own email as the from email, do you know of anything "bad' that might happen? Security/vulnerability/etc

Comment: You'll get an email where your own address is the return address. That's all.

Comment: @nodel - The most common from email address is `noreply@<yourdomain.com>`. I bet you've got a lot of those in your inbox right now.